# fct_collapse function to multiple columns at once

Tags: r, refactoring, forcats

I got a dataset where yes / no variables all have been entered as free text (facepalm).

At first I tried to apply the fct_collapse function to every individual column in the dataframe, but this takes a lot of coding considering there are 50+ columns with yes and no.

```
pid = c(1,2,3,4,5)
a = c("y", "Y", "no", "no", "NO")
b = c("yes", "Y", "y", "no", "n")
c = c("Y", "no", "n", "no", "No")
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I tried

```
df$a <- fct_collapse(df$a, yes = c("y", "Y"), no = c("no", "NO")
```

But I guess this will take many lines of code. Is it possible to do it with one line of code with an apply function or mutate in combination with across?

EDIT: the output I am looking for is

```
a2 = c("yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no")
b2 = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no")
c2 = c("yes", "no", "no", "no", "no")
df2 <- data.frame(pid,a2,b2,c2)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry! made an edit to the question with the output that i am lookin for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `across` to loop over the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(-pid, ~ fct_collapse(.,
     yes = c('y', 'Y'), no = c('no', 'NO', 'n'))))
```

-output

```
#   pid   a   b   c
#1   1 yes yes yes
#2   2 yes yes  no
#3   3  no yes  no
#4   4  no  no  no
#5   5  no  no  No
```

Comment: Thank you! A newby asking here: what is the ~ and the <dot>, for?

Comment: @JuliusHeemelaar it is just a lambda call in tidyverse which is equivalent to `function(x) x` here, it is `.`

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x `f` must be a factor (or character vector).
i Input `..1` is `across(...)`.

Comment: @JuliusHeemelaar Do you also have a `pid` column

Comment: @JuliusHeemelaar in the example you created `df <- data.frame(a, b, c)`. I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to use `mgsub` like so

```
mgsub::mgsub(df, 
             c("Y", "yes", "y", "n", "NO", "no", "No"), 
             c("yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no"))
```

**Output**

```
  pid   a   b   c
1   1 yes yes yes
2   2 yes yes  no
3   3  no yes  no
4   4  no  no  no
5   5  no  no  no
```